# Gradle build issues with Datahub spark-lineage

Tags: gradle

Following is the gradle file https://github.com/datahub-project/datahub/blob/master/metadata-integration/java/spark-lineage/build.gradle that am trying to build but see issues with Gradle version 8.0.2.

Particularly the below one.

> caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'externalDependency' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Tried to search through Gradle API docs, could not find much information. Please assist.